# Name Entity Linking with Naive Bayes Classifier

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, multiclass-classification, naive-bayes-classifier

I was trying to absolve one name entity resolution problem.
Suppose, I have two sentences,

Cameron is the PM of England . He decided to step down .

Cameron was trying to keep England in EU . Mr. Cameron could not do it .

These two sentences have two different properties, first contains a pronoun, and second one alias against Cameron. My objective is to determine the entities(NE or otherwise) and link the entities appropriately, considering pronoun and alias are entities.

I have divided the task in two phrases.

In the first I am using one entity extraction algorithm, and in the second, trying to link them.

I am trying to use Supervised Learning algorithm for both of them.

I used one Hidden Markov Model(HMM) to extract the entities.

I had given user defined training set and extracted entities as,

Cameron/PERS is/NA the/NA PM/EXE of/NA England/LOC ./NA He/PRN decided/NA to/NA step/NA down/NA ./NA

and,

Cameron/PERS was/NA trying/NA to/NA keep/NA England/LOC in EU/ORG ./NA Mr./TIT Cameron/PERS could/NA not/NA do/NA it/NA ./NA

I am using one standard Naive Bayes(NB) classifier to classify these two sentences belonging to two groups.

The first one being 'PRN-STRING' and second one 'ALIAS'.

I am using a new training set in NB classifier, and classifying the extracted sentences.

The first is being labelled as 'PRN-STRING' and second 'ALIAS'.

My questions are

(i) Am I doing right? As much I read about entity linking I am going right, my friends and seniors also say so.

(ii) Classification and extraction tasks are independent, but am I right to combine in the same code?

In my code I am tagging with HMM and after some processing of the output, pushing as input to the classifier.

NB: EXE-> It is a User defined tag as Executive.